# why I can't use function readframe in matlab

Tags: matlab

I write this code but have error "Undefined function 'readframe' for input arguments of type 'VideoReader'"
How to I will solve? thank you.

```
v = VideoReader('filename.avi');
video = readframe(v,1);
figVid = figure();
axeVid = axes('Parent', figVid);
image(video, 'Parent', axeVid);
```

Comment: What version of matlab are you using?

Comment: I use version R2015a

Comment: change readframe to readFrame

Comment: Correctly. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actual Answer: The function is readFrame() not readframe().